# Could we use a font where 'l' doesn't look identical to 'I'?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've been perusing a few posts here and there, and one thing that sometimes confuses me is seeing an 'l' and thinking that it is an 'I'. An example is the question about [ClF3](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/698/flammability-nfpa-how-is-it-defined/699) ($\ce {ClF3}$) which I know is obviously NOT CIF3 ($\ce {CIF3}$) but which managed to confuse me for a minute or so nonetheless. I guess the other fonts that cause problems are ones where 'l' looks like '1' such as many monospaced fonts!

Really, I guess it's a fairly minor thing, but I was wondering about what the rest of you guys thought?

Comment: We can check into it, but I don't think we have much control over that, it's done with a master CSS sheet for all of the beta sites.  You could, however, write your own CSS sheet which changes the font or the style, I think.  I'll let Manish weigh in on that part.

Comment: Regardless of the MathJax clarifications and such, I generally approve of not using Arial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's pretty unambiguous in MathJax (I edited that post to fix this), though I'll admit that I've been confused at times with `mhchem`-formatted formulae in other places. Still, the easiest thing to do is always use MathJax for formulae on this site.

You can fix this on your side by installing [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) ([Stylish for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)) and changing the `font-face` for `.post-text` to a font with a clearer I-l distinction. The same goes for the `.mtext` MathJax class if you feel that it's still ambiguous.

Update: [Stylish script](http://userstyles.org/styles/92357/stackexchange-change-font-no-ambiguous-l), credit @Snipergirl

Comment: good point. perhaps next when I get confused by a formula that isn't in mathjax or mhchem I'll edit it so that it is?

Comment: @Snipergirl Yep. In general, it's best to mathjax-ify most formulae.

Comment: I've added a Stylish userstyle here: http://userstyles.org/styles/92357/stackexchange-change-font-no-ambiguous-l